# React Redux: Update and replace records with another records returns value of 1

Tags: reactjs, redux

React Redux: Update and replace records with another records returns value of 1.

On the server side, I have a json response `[{"id":"10", "food_name":"Rice"}]`

The code below works fine by displaying a food item called **Rice** from the database via API Call as showed in the json array above.

Now I have a requirements to replace the displayed food item **Rice** with **Beans**.

To this effect, I have a json files which is to be returned via API Call after posting

```
[{"id":"10", "food_name":"Beans"}]
```

I have also created a Post button which should send data to the server side and return the response Beans.

Here is my effort as well as my Issue which is caused by reducer.

If Implement the code below in the reducer

```
case foodConstants.FOOD_SUCCESS_POST:
 return {
items: state.items.map(food1 => {
        if (food1.id === action.id) {
//return { ...food1, food_name: state.items[0].food_name};
return { ...food1, food_name: 'Beans' };
          }
```

The Code works fine and **Rice** is replaced with **Beans** since I set value beans in the reducer.

but since I need to get the records via API Call so if implement

```
case foodConstants.FOOD_SUCCESS_POST:
 return {
items: state.items.map(food1 => {
        if (food1.id === action.id) {
return { ...food1, food_name: state.items[0].food_name};
          }
```

Am getting value of **1** replacing **Rice** instead of **Beans**. Please where is this value of **1** coming from.
I need to have beans replace record Rice as a value returned from API Call.
My action and service code are okay as I can see the json returned records in the array as per

```
[{"id":"10", "food_name":"Beans"}]
```

I think my problem lies in this line of code below which returns value of 1 instaed of Beans.

```
return { ...food1, food_name: state.items[0].food_name};
```

**Here is the full code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { foodActions } from 'actions';

class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
this.state = {};

    }
    componentDidMount() {
this.props.dispatch(foodActions.getFood());
    }

 handleFood(id,food_type) {
    return (e) => this.props.dispatch(foodActions.postfood(food_id));

    }

    render() {
        const { food1, foods1 } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>           
   {foods1.items &&
                    <ul>
                        {foods1.items.map((food1, index1) =>
                            <li key={food1.id}>
                                {food1.food_name} 
<input type="button" value="Post and Update Food Name"  onClick={this.handleFood(food1.id)}  />
</li>
                        )}

                    </ul>
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {

    const { foods1} = state;
    const { food1 } = state;
    return {
        food1, foods1
    };
}

const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
export { connectedApp as App };
```

**Reducer Code**

```
import { foodConstants } from '/constants';
export function foods1(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

case foodConstants.GETALL_REQUEST:
  return {loading: true};
case foodConstants.GETALL_SUCCESS:
  return {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
items: action.foods1,
  };
case foodConstants.GETALL_FAILURE:
      return { 
        error: action.error
      };


// Post and Update Food Name

 case foodConstants.FOOD_REQUEST_POST:
 return {...state};
 case foodConstants.FOOD_SUCCESS_POST:
 return {
items: state.items.map(food1 => {
        if (food1.id === action.id) {
return { ...food1, food_name: state.items[0].food_name};

          }

          return food1;
        })
      };
    case foodConstants.FOOD_FAILURE_POST:
 return { 
        error: action.error
      };

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Please great Stackoverflow Engineers, any solution or suggestions will be highly appreciated. Am counting  on you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace value that is coming in action, but you are picking from state

```
case foodConstants.FOOD_SUCCESS_POST: {

  const updatedItems = state.items.map((food1) => {
    if (food1.id === action.id) {
      return { ...action };
    }

    return food1;
  });
 return { ...state, items: updatedItems };
}
```

**Or you can do this as well**

```
case foodConstants.FOOD_SUCCESS_POST: {

  let updatedItems = { ...state.items };
  const itemIndex = updatedItems.findIndex((food1) => food1.id === action.id);

  if(itemIndex > -1){
    updatedItems[itemIndex] = {
        ...updatedItems[itemIndex],
        ...action,
    }
  }

 return { ...state, items: updatedItems };
}
```

Comment: Hope I was not late for answer :)